# where can i download minimum JRE?

Tags: installation, java

where can i download minimum JRE with out swing?

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere legally, because you are not allowed to modify rt.jar and redistribute it.

Answer (score 1):

The Swing compiled classes are part of the **rt.jar** file that comes with the JRE. Simply put, the **rt.jar** file which is a unit, containing all standart java classes (Swing included) in compiled form. The jar file is there so that you do not need to bundle it with your application.

As of Java 6, there is no way to distribute/use only parts of that jar file legally. Java 7 with Project Jigsaw is planning on modularizing the runtime and splitting this into modules which you can selectively use, but AFAIK, project Jigsaw got pushed back for Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* you can. You can download the JRE [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), but it's going to have Swing support. You could grab an [embedded version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/embedded-jsp-135769.html) instead, but I don't think that's likely to be what you want. You could grab the main JRE and then remove the `javax.swing` tree in `rt.jar` file (for your own personal use), but I'm not sure that's going to gain you much...